# Find (AND remove) hashtags as they are being typed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For a textinput field, I'm able to 'collect' hashtags as they are being entered.

- User input: `If #this is #entered, hellooooooo blah blah`.
- `hashtags === ['#this', '#entered'] // true.`;

FYI the way how I 'find' hashtags is whenever a 'space' is entered, a function will check the last word to see if it starts with `#`. (Is there a more efficient way to find them?)

The problem is that the user is also able to 'remove' hashtags by deleting characters. **I am stuck on how to get them removed (efficiently).**

- Updated user input: `If #this is // User has removed the other stuff.`
- updated `hashtags === ['#this'] // true; '#entered' has been removed.`

Please help!

Comment: maybe use regex to parse the input value and find all matches on every change rather than hack the words to see if it starts with #?

Comment: What I would recommend is, just watch every input user made with a debounced function, and check if there is any hashtag matching in your string.

That way no matter how they put hashtags there (including copy and paste), you can capture them.

You can imagine youtube search, you just type and type, when you stop, it shows the relative results.

Comment: If the input is `'#this'` is the intended outcome to slice out just the `#`? Or the whole # plus the word?

Comment: @Tugayİlik, thanks for the tip. (Still, not sure how to 'remove' hashtags)

Comment: If you only capture and override them, you don't need to remove them. But if you need to remove them from an array after the first initialization, I recommend intersecting two arrays and removing the remaining ones. @daCoda

Answer (score 2):

You should always rescan and extract all hashtags, as checking the last word is not complete. What if a user moves the cursor at the start and adds a hashtag there ? or what if a user edits a character at the middle of a hashtag?

So, you could use `onInput` which will also fire on pasting text and do

```
const checkForHashtags = useCallback((e) => {
  const text = e.currentTarget.value;
  const hashtags = text.match(/#[a-z0-9_]+/gi);
  // setTags( hashtags ); // add the tags to state if you need to
  // console.log(hashtags);
}, []);
```

and then on your input add

```
onInput={checkForHashtags}
```

---

Additionally, as mentioned in a comment, you could debounce that method so that it waits a little before processing the text, so as to not run while the user is typing.

Comment: Yeah that's what I wanted to avoid - having to rescan the whole text every time. Is there a better way...